# Call a stored procedure which contains parameters and output param from another stored procedure?

Tags: sql, t-sql

This is just an example to demonstrate.

Stored procedure A:

```
Create PROCEDURE InsertNode

@ID nvarchar(64),
@Name nvarchar(64),
@Total int OUTPUT
AS
INSERT INTO [TableA] (ID,Name) VALUES (@ID, @Name)
SELECT @Total = Count(*) FROM TableA
```

Stored procedure B:

```
Create PROCEDURE CallInsertNode

@InputID nvarchar(64),
@InputName nvarchar(64),
@ResultTotal
AS
EXEC InsertNode ...// how can I define the input params(@InputID, @Input Name) and output param (@ResultTotal) for Stored procedure A (like passing parameters)?
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
EXEC InsertNode 
    @Id = @InputId,
    @Name = @InputName,
    @Total = @ResultTotal OUTPUT
```